# 13.10->14.04 upgrade hangs on mdadm configure

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I have a Ubuntu 13.10 Server installation. I'm trying to get it to 14.04 using

```
do-release-upgrade
```

It hangs when it tries to configure mdadm, I see this in the terminal:

```
Setting up mdadm (3.2.5-5ubuntu4) ...
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/mdadm-raid ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-grub is /usr/sbin/update-grub
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.5.0-27-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.0.0-26-generic
```

If I ctrl-C at this point (after waiting for 30 mins!), it carries on with the rest of the upgrade, but I'm left with the instruction to do a

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

at the end.

And when I do, it does the same at the same point.

Any idea what's happening and how I get this upgrade to finish?

Any pointers welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Someone smart suggested that I didn't need `mdadm`. So I removed it, and then all was good, upgrade completed smoothly.